# Computing coordinates of a rectangle within a rectangle after resizing

Tags: geometry

I am working on a game project that requires the objects to scale automatically as the screen size of device varies, so that the game is able to run on screens of different sizes. The following figure explains my problem. The rectangle on left has all the coordinates known for both inner and outer rectangle. When I resize the rectangle it appears on right, with new coordinates. However, I am unable to figure out how to mathematically find the exact values of x1, x2, x3, x4.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compute the scale factor, which is
$$k=\frac{\text{width of large rectangle after resizing}}{\text{width of large rectangle before resizing}}$$
Heights can be used instead of widths.

Then multiply every coordinate in the small rectangle by $k$ to get their values after resizing. In this case, $k=\frac{720}{1080}=\frac23$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so beautifully.